# Android TextView not updating - nothing has worked so far

Tags: android, textview, updates

There are a LOT of postings about TextView's not updating and there are a LOT of suggestions/advice on how to resolve the problem.

I think that I have tried most, if not all, of them and have not yet solved the problem.

In general, my code is as follows:

```
private String RefreshUpdateMsg = "Updating";
TextView txtRefresh;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.updateroutesform);  
   myActivity = this;  

   txtRefresh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRefreshing);  

   Button btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
   btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launch Alert Dialog and Acquire New Data
            ConfirmUpdate();
        }
    });

   if (IntegrateData.equals("YES")) {
        //txtRefresh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRefreshing);
        txtRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtRefresh.setText(RefreshUpdateMsg);  // THIS SHOWS FINE

        // Launch Handler to Integrate the NewData
        mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchIntegration,1000);
    }  
}
```

The first time through the onCreate(), the "IntegrateData" is set to "NO" so the GUI waits for the user to click the btnUpdate and launch the Alert Dialog.

The Alert Dialog (if YES is clicked) will **finish()** this form and run another one.
On completing the new data acquisition (a Text File) in the other form, it will again launch this form, but have the IntegrateData 'flag' set to "YES"

This will launch the Handler to integrate the data.
All is working OK up to this point.

Now, within the Handler, in addition to reading the new File and writing its data to my SQLite database table, I am trying to update the TextView 'txtRefresh' to show the status of the slow data integration.

At different times (not all in sequence like shown below), I tried each of the following:

```
// -----------------------------------------
txtRefresh.setText("New Text");  
txtRefresh.invalidate();   // DID NOT WORK  

// -----------------------------------------
txtRefresh.setText("New Text");  
txtRefresh.postInvalidate();   // DID NOT WORK  

// -----------------------------------------
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         ((TextView) txtRefresh).setText("New Text"); // DID NOT WORK
                                }
       });

// -----------------------------------------
myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     txtRefresh.setText("New Text");  // DID NOT WORK
  }
});


// -----------------------------------------
// -- I even tried launching a new, separate Handler to just update the  
// -- TextView, but it too did not work
```

None of those separate approaches worked.
Either I am doing something wrong, or I need to different approach.

Any suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why is `RefreshUpdateMsg` declared a `TextView` but used as a `string`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That was a typo on my part in this posting - not in my actual code.  It is really defined as a String (see Edit above)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this set. You were using a TextView as a String and you were also re-initialisng the text view. Just double check you have txtRefresh declared above.

```
String refreshUpdateMsg = "Updating...";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.updateroutesform);   

   txtRefresh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRefreshing);  
   Button btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

   btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launch Alert Dialog and Acquire New Data
            ConfirmUpdate();
        }
    });

   if (IntegrateData.equals("YES")) {
        txtRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //removable if you haven't set the visibility to GONE or INVISIBLE in your xml 
        txtRefresh.setText(refreshUpdateMsg);  // THIS SHOWS FINE

        // Launch Handler to Integrate the NewData
        mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchIntegration,1000);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Both were typos in this posting.  (see Edits in original code above).  The Updates still do not work.

Comment: @Dhugalmac you are still reinitialising textview.
 you have called 
txtRefresh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRefreshing);  twice

Comment: OK, I have now eliminated any reinitialization of the TextView txtRefreshing (see Edited code above).  I only do it once in the onCreate().   The Updates are still not working.

Comment: try debugging and seeing if it actually goes inside of that if statement. if you don't know how to use the debugger use a toast or a log statement @Dhugalmac

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Using Breakpoints I have confirmed that the code does go into the if (IntegrateData.equals("YES")) {}  and then the Handler mLaunchIntegration  calls/launches a subsequent IntegrateNewData() routine.   That routine also runs fine and Breakpoints there show that it SHOULD be updating the TextView periodically.   But those Updates never appear on the GUI - regardless of approach that I have tried.

Comment: Try checking to making sure you are using the right Id for the textView. Sometimes it doesn't read as an error but the R import is sometimes incorrect and points to the wrong view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  One of the previous replies suggested that I cut all of my 'definitions' of the TextView txtRefreshing down to one single on in the onCreate method.  I did that.   With only a single confirmed working TextView id 'definition', how/where can it go wrong.